# Are multi-stage work forms and approvals possible?

Tags: powerapps

I have  3 forms in PowerApps:
FormA
FormB
FormC

Required App operation:

- When a user clicks "new request", **FormA** is created and filled out by the originator.
- The originator selects which department they need, "Furniture, Tech, Food" for example.
- **Department1** receives this request and now gets presented with **FormB**
- **Department1** fills out **FormB** and selects the next appropriate delegate in another department, **Department2**.
- **Department2** now receives **FormC** to fill out and finally approve.

Is such an operation possible within PowerApps? I'm aware you can have cascaded approvals with Flow however the user isn't presented with a form - Only simple options within an email.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do that. I guess you already googled this out.

[Take a look at this answer, this gives all the idea you need to show different screen/forms based on some values.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Load-powerapps-screen-based-on-sharepoint-item-property-value/m-p/176837/highlight/true#M58648)

You can definitely extend the logic based on your req.